# Can an event with probability $0$ still happen?

Tags: probability

For instance suppoze we have an agent that equiprobably selects a number in the real interval$[0,1]$. What is the probability that the agent will chose exactly $0.23$

By the definition $P(0.23) = \frac{1}{Num \> of\> all \>events} $

Which can be written as dividing one to an expression the limens of which is infinity. the question is, is the probability exactly $0$ or does it tend to $0$.

Comment: The probability you're talking about just approaches $0$, it is not exactly $0$. Since, $0.23$ belongs to sample  space, so we can never have probability of getting $0.23$=$0$

Comment: @user75659 That's not true, at all. $P(0.23) = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really "equiprobably selects a number", it's "samples a number from the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$".  In all continuous probability distributions, the probability of selecting any given real number is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The mathematics of probability is a model of the world, so it makes no sense to ask if something with probability $0$ can "really happen".

When the sample space is finite you generally don't include elements with probability $0$. When rolling a die you don't think about whether you will see a $7$.

When choosing a "random" real number from the interval $[0,1]$ the standard model does indeed say that the probability of $0.5$ is $0$. But that's only a model. If you were measuring you could never see exactly $0.5$. In the standard model you could say something about the probability that your measurement was between $0.49$ and $0.51$.

Comment: If you did get exactly $0.5$, you wouldn't know it, because you can't measure continuous variables exactly.  All you could say is that you got a number that was so close to $0.5$ you couldn't tell the difference between it and $0.5$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Pick a number $x$ from $[0, 1]$ uniformly. The probability that $x$ is picked is $0$, but it just happened.

Comment: You mis-understand probability, which (in this case) describes a state of uncertainty *before* a sample is taken.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The uniform distribution didn't change after I took my sample.

Comment: Sorry, you are simply mistaken.  *AFTER* a point has been selected (even in a uniform *discrete* case) its "probability" for the given selection is not $1/n$... instead it is a certainty.  The probability it is chosen *again* is $1/n$.  It is a non-sensical as stating "the probability of rain yesterday is 30\%" (or whatever).  (Of course you can say that before then, the probability of rain for yesterday was $30\%$... because it is describing a state of uncertainty in its then future.)

Comment: Nothing I said disagrees with what you said.

Comment: Sample a number $x$ from $[0, 1]$ uniformly. Which of my claims do you specifically disagree with: 1. $x$ just happened, or 2., $P(x) = 0$.?

Comment: Perhaps the ambiguity is the use of small x (a particular value) and big X (a random variable). Or you can put it this way: If you have two iid variables X,Y uniform over [0,1], the probability that Y takes the same value as X is 0.

Comment: Here is what @Duncan Ramage said that is incorrectly interpreted:  "Pick a number  from [0,1] uniformly. The probability that  is picked is 0, but it just happened."  He is incorrect in his last statement.  If "it just happened" then it is a certainty.  What he should have instead said is:  "Before any real number is picked, the probability that any particular real number (call it "$x$") is chosen is zero.  Of course when we pick we get *a* number.  But the probability it is the prior chosen number $x$ is in fact $0$."  *THAT* (different) statement would be correct.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork You are talking about $P(x | x)$. I am talking about $P(x)$. $P(x) = 0$ before $x$ is picked, $P(x) = 0$ after $x$ is picked. The distribution didn't change.